# Can't sign-in Xbox Windows 8.1 - Error 0xc00d11cd (0x80004005)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-games

When I try to sign-in in Xbox games in Windows 8.1, I write my password and when I click ok, it returns the following error:

> Xbox service is not available at the moment
>   Try again. If the problem stills visit www.xbox.com/support for help
>   ...
>   0xc00d11cd (0x80004005)

[image: Error image]

I already verified Xbox status at https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status but it is "up and running"

Already reinstalled Windows 8.1 and the problem stills

How can I fix this error?

---

Sorry if i'm misssing anything, i'm new user to Windows, I was using Mac OSX and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I instaled all updates with Windows Update the problem solved itself.

Answer (score 2):

After hearing of changes to my contract with Xbox, I solved this problem by logging into http://www.xbox.com/support with my account, then accepted the contract's modifications.  (I was unable to find the latest updates!)